# Hiding hours axis for a Vaadin calendar

Tags: java, calendar, vaadin

I need to display more than one calendar in a view in a HorizentalLayout. And as the calendars are bonded to each other, I want to display the hours axis only for the first calendar from the left.

Is-it possible ?

Update : this is the current version of my code. It's quite simple and just create Calendars in a fixed loop... the code is in the constructor of my view

```
private List<Calendar> listOfCals = new ArrayList<>();

public PostageViewAsManyCalendars() {

    root.setMargin(true);

    int hour = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Calendar cal = new Calendar("My Calendar");
        cal.setWidth("150px");
        cal.setHeight("400px");
        listOfCals.add(cal);

        cal.setStartDate(new GregorianCalendar(2012, 1, 14, 00, 00).getTime());
        cal.setEndDate(new GregorianCalendar(2012, 1, 14, 23, 59).getTime());

        // Use a container of built-in BasicEvents
        final BeanItemContainer<BasicEvent> container = new BeanItemContainer<BasicEvent>(BasicEvent.class);

        // Create a meeting in the container
        container.addBean(
                new BasicEvent("The Event", "Single Event", new GregorianCalendar(2012, 1, 14, hour, 00).getTime(),
                        new GregorianCalendar(2012, 1, hour + 3, 14, 00).getTime()));

        // The container must be ordered by the start time. You
        // have to sort the BIC every time after you have added
        // or modified events.
        container.sort(new Object[] { "start" }, new boolean[] { true });
        cal.setContainerDataSource(container, "caption", "description", "start", "end", "styleName");

        root.addComponent(cal);
        hour++;
    }

    this.setCompositionRoot(root);
}
```

What I want to hide is the axis hour as noticed bellow :

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ak8O.png)

Comment: please post what you have tried ...

Comment: It is possible. Post some code

Comment: @kukis I have updated my post to include le current version of my code and an image for clarification. Thx

Comment: @kukis how is it possible ?

Comment: You have to use css. Will look into it after the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique based on the css changes is not enough. Any change in a css class will be applied to all calendars, which is not goo for me because I need to display the time bar for the first one...

To test that change the following css class as below :

```css
.v-calendar-times {
    width: 0px;
    font-size: 0.77em;
    line-height: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; 
    color:transparent;    
}
```

I spent some time to look to Vaadin code. **My conclusion is that this kind of customization is not expected, and you have to use the calendar ASIS**. Extending the code is quite complex because the time bar (Timebar) is an inner class inside com.vaadin.client.ui.calendar.schedule.WeekGrid, and will be expensive to rewrite this client side...

For additional info read this post :

https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/10491292

Answer (score 0):

Finally I succeed to put in place a solution based on Vaadin 7 extension mechanism. The Java extension manipulates the default generated DOM, and remove, modify or add css classes according to the display I want to have...

At end I get the following view, which in this example has 4 calendars :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSx8j.png)

More information about Vaadin 7 extensions :
[enter link description here](https://blog.oio.de/2014/01/21/vaadin-extension-highlighting-custom-components-during-development/)

The main part of my code is the Connector class which makes the DOM transformations :

@Connect(CalendarExtension.class)
public class CalendarExtensionConnector extends AbstractExtensionConnector {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8722803624865597642L;

private VCalendar vcalendar;

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.vaadin.client.extensions.AbstractExtensionConnector#extend(com.vaadin.client.ServerConnector)
 */
@Override
protected void extend(ServerConnector target) {

    vcalendar = (VCalendar) ((ComponentConnector) target).getWidget();

    // I have tested many other handlers but does not work : AttachEvent.Handler, LoadHandler, InitializeHandler,
    // OpenHandler, ValueChangeHandler

    // weekGrid is a property in VCalendar, and it contains the famous TimeBar !
    target.addStateChangeHandler("weekGrid", new StateChangeEvent.StateChangeHandler() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8439729365677484553L;

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(StateChangeEvent stateChangeEvent) {
            Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    Element element = vcalendar.getElement();

                    // add css classes
                    addClassName(element, getState().cssClasses2Add);

                    // set exact properties
                    setExactProperties4ExactClassName(element, getState().exactStyleProperties);

                    // remove elements
                    removeChildrenByClassName(element, getState().cssClasses4Remove);

                }

            });
        }
    });

}

/**
 * @param element
 * @param extProperties
 */
private void setExactProperties4ExactClassName(Element element, List<String> extProperties) {
    for (String prop : extProperties) {
        String[] props = prop.split(",");
        String class2Search = props[0];
        String propertyName = props[1];
        String propertyValue = props[2];
        List<Element> exacts = DomUtils.findElementsByExactClass(element, class2Search);
        if (exacts != null) {
            for (Element exa : exacts) {
                exa.getStyle().setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void addClassName(Element element, List<String> cssClasses2Add) {
    for (String prop : cssClasses2Add) {
        String[] props = prop.split(",");
        String class2Search = props[0];
        String class2Add = props[1];

        List<Element> exacts = DomUtils.findElementsByExactClass(element, class2Search);
        if (exacts != null) {
            for (Element exa : exacts) {
                exa.addClassName(class2Add);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param element
 * @param className
 */
private void removeChildrenByClassName(Element element, String... classNames) {
    List<Element> items = DomUtils.findElementsForClass(element, classNames);
    if ((items != null) && (items.size() > 0)) {
        for (Element element2 : items) {
            element2.removeFromParent();
        }
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector#getState()
 */
@Override
public CalendarExtensionState getState() {
    return (CalendarExtensionState) super.getState();
}
```

}

My DomUtils i quite simple :

```
public class DomUtils {

public static List findElementsForClass(Element element, String... classNames) {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    recElementsForClass(result, element, classNames);
    return result;
}

private static void recElementsForClass(ArrayList res, Element element, String... classNames) {
    String c;

    if (element == null) {
        return;
    }

    c = DOM.getAttribute(element, "className");

    if (c != null) {
        String[] p = c.split(" ");

        for (String element2 : p) {
            for (String className : classNames) {
                if (element2.equals(className)) {
                    res.add(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DOM.getChildCount(element); i++) {
        Element child = DOM.getChild(element, i);
        recElementsForClass(res, child, classNames);
    }
}

public static List findElementsByExactClass(Element element, String className) {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    recElementsForExactClass(result, element, className);
    return result;
}

private static void recElementsForExactClass(ArrayList res, Element element, String className) {
    String c;

    if (element == null) {
        return;
    }

    c = DOM.getAttribute(element, "className");

    if (c != null) {
        if (c.equals(className)) {
            res.add(element);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DOM.getChildCount(element); i++) {
        Element child = DOM.getChild(element, i);
        recElementsForExactClass(res, child, className);
    }
}
```

}

To share data between the connector and the server side class (CalendarExtension), you need to have custom shared state. Look to the vaadin wiki for that. In my case it's the CalendarExtensionState class...

Good luck